# Entitiy Manager doesn't answer before native query call ends

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate and Oracle SQL in my project. When I call createNativeQuery method of the entity Manager, the entity manager doesn't answer any call (even from different browsers) before the method returns. The query takes long time but it is called in new a thread. Why is the entity manager blocked?

**NOTE: When I call JPQL query, the problem disappears.**

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

//blocking other transactions, cannot make any read from the same entityManager until this method is completed.
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void testMethod1(String query) {

    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
// CANNOT SET LOCKMODE because it is not JPQL :  q.setLockMode(LockModeType.NONE)  //throws exception
    List<Object[]> result =  q.getResultList();
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void testMethod2(String jpql) {

    Query q = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
    List<Object> result =  q.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your query which is passing to createNativeQuery(query) method.

Comment: It contains just select statements.

Comment: which version of hibernate & javaee are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem using other databases (SQL Anywhere in my case).

After this I took a look at [Hibernate JavaDocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/QueryHints.html) and it says that your problem is the default behavior, because JPA requires that setLockMode should be applied only on non-native queries.

To have a workaround to this, Hibernate makes use of the QueryHints of the query:

**NATIVE_LOCKMODE**: 
Available to apply lock mode to a native SQL query since JPA requires that Query.setLockMode(javax.persistence.LockModeType) throw an IllegalStateException if called for a native query.

To use QueryHints you should do something like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void testMethod1(String query) {

    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
    q.setHint(QueryHints.NATIVE_LOCKMODE, LockModeType.NONE);
    List<Object[]> result =  q.getResultList();
}
```

I have also identified that if you use the @TransactionAttribute above your method the problem might not occur, example:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void testMethod1(String query) {

    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
    q.setHint(QueryHints.NATIVE_LOCKMODE, LockModeType.NONE);
    List<Object[]> result =  q.getResultList();
}
```

Please, try the solutions given above and let us know if the problem was solved or not, good luck!